# An Adjustable horizontal line with CSS.

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to achieve an adjustable horizontal line with CSS.

HTML

```
<div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-around title">
    <span style=" flex-shrink: 3;"  class="align-self-center"></span>
    <h5> content here </h5>
    <span style=" flex-shrink: 3;" class="align-self-center"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.title span {
    height: 1px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    width: 33%;
}
```

[image: short content]

When the content is short, it looks very perfect.

[image: long content]

However, if the content is too long. It will disarray like this. Are there any ways to make an adjustable line with CSS?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like what you really want to do is center the text.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way using flexbox and pseudo-classes for the bars - no tricks and just one element inside the container.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* vertically center lines */
}

div::before,
div::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1; /* expand lines as much as possible */
  background: #ccc;
  height: 2px;
}

span {
  padding: 0 1em; /* slight padding between line and text */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Text of any size</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you out. Just note that the `background-color` for the element `h5` should be same as the background of the page

**JSFiddle:** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/as1cjp3x/2/)

```css
.title span {
    height: 1px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    width: 33%;
}
hr{
  margin:60px 0px;
  width:100%;
}
h5{
  position:absolute;
  margin:0px auto;
  background-color:white;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  font-size:20px;
}
.vcenter{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="vcenter">
  <hr>
  <h5> content here which is like very long and cant handle it </h5>
</div>
```

If you want the text to expand only to a certain limit and text should be centered check the below example.

```css
.title span {
    height: 1px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    width: 33%;
}
hr{
  margin:60px 0px;
  width:100%;
}
h5{
  position:absolute;
  max-width:300px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0px auto;
  background-color:white;
      padding: 3% 5%;
  font-size:20px;
  max-width:300px; 
}
.vcenter{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="vcenter">
  <hr>
  <h5 class="vcenter"> content here which is like very long and cant handle it </h5>
</div>
```